# Update GMSMarker location as realtime message received Swift 3.1

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift3, delegates, messaging

I am new to swift. I am working on an app which shows markers moving on location update when realtime message is received.

**View and Steps**

1. Home (Map Screen which will show tracking results) and Search Button
2. On search button click, a new search view has been displayed. User
   types and search
3. On search result view if found, a table view is shown. User can
   select multiple to subscribe and "Add to tracking list"

On "Add to tracking list", app subscribe on realtime api and should start displaying results (on first view - Home) as message received.

**Issue:**
I am using delegate to share data (method: messageReceived) from MesssagingProcessor class to FirstViewController. Problem is "messageReceived" is not called in MesssagingProcessor class because delegate is nil.

**To go back to first, I used following code**

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

**To subscribe,**

```
channel.subscribe { message in
                    print(message.name ?? Constant.NIL_DEFAULT_TEXT)
                    print(message.data ?? Constant.NIL_DEFAULT_TEXT)
                    self.messageProcessor.process(message: message)
                }
                return true
```

I am using delegate to share data between classes and viewcontrollers

**Delegate Class:**

```
protocol MesssagingProcessorDelegate {
    func messageReceived(msg: MessageMO)
}

class MesssagingProcessor {

    //MAR: Properties
    var delegate: MesssagingProcessorDelegate?
    var info = ""

    //MARK: Constructor
    init() {
        info = "I am set"
    }

    //MARK: Functions
    func process(message: <MessageTypeHere>) {
        let msg = MessageMO(dataString: message.data as! String, colString: Constant.EP.C_MSG)
        if MessagingHelper.validMessage(msg: msg) {
            if msg.type == Constant.TYPE_MSG_LOC {
                if msg.location != nil {
                    delegate?.messageReceived(msg: msg)
                }
                else {
                    print("No location found in Location Message. Message: \(String(describing: message.data))")
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Home View Controller:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import UserNotifications

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, MesssagingProcessorDelegate {


    //MARK: Properties

    let messsagingProcessor: MesssagingProcessor = MesssagingProcessor()

    var bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds()
    var mapView: GMSMapView? = nil

    //MARK: Events
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let button = UIButton.init(type: .custom)
        button.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "logo"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(showTrackeeOptions), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        button.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30) //CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: button)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton


        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 53.34624,
                                              longitude: -6.24134, zoom: 6)
        mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
        mapView!.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        mapView!.settings.setAllGesturesEnabled(true)
        mapView!.delegate = self
        self.view = mapView!
//
        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20)
        marker.title = "TEST"
        marker.snippet = Generic.toImageURL(name: "_demo_bus.png", category: Constant.TYPE_IMG_MARKER, type: Constant.TYPE_USER) + "^TestTest Test <-> Demo Bus^Available^2.3 km/h^1493729075106^10^0^333"
        marker.map = mapView!

        messsagingProcessor.delegate = self

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //MARK: Events

    //MARK: MesssagingProcessorDelegate
    func messageReceived(msg: MessageMO) {

        let mk = MarkerMO(msg: msg).add()
        var marker: GMSMarker

        if mk != nil {

            let imgURL = Generic.toImageURL(name: mk!.iconMarker, category: Constant.TYPE_IMG_MARKER, type: Constant.TYPE_USER)
            var sharedInfo = imgURL
            sharedInfo += Constant.SEPARATOR_LIST_ITEM
            sharedInfo += mk!.name! + Constant.SEPARATOR_LIST_ITEM
            sharedInfo += mk!.status + Constant.SEPARATOR_LIST_ITEM
            sharedInfo += mk!.speed + Constant.SEPARATOR_LIST_ITEM
            sharedInfo += String(mk!.time) + Constant.SEPARATOR_LIST_ITEM
            sharedInfo += String(mk!.interval)

            if mk!.gMarker != nil {
                marker = GMSMarker()
            } else {
                marker = mk!.gMarker!
            }

            CATransaction.begin()
            CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(1.0)

            marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (mk!.location!.latitude), longitude: (mk!.location!.longitude))
            marker.icon = Generic.toImageByURL(url: imgURL, width: Constant.ICON_DEFAULT_MARKER_WIDTH, height: Constant.ICON_DEFAULT_MARKER_HEIGHT, defaultImage: "defaultmarker")

            marker.title = mk!.name
            marker.snippet = sharedInfo
            marker.map = self.mapView

            CATransaction.commit()

            mk!.updateGMarker(marker: marker)
            self.bounds = self.bounds.includingCoordinate(marker.position)

        }
        else {
            //TODO: Error in marker generation
        }



    }


}

extension FirstViewController: GMSMapViewDelegate {
        //For Info WindowIndow
        func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {
            let infoWindow = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("LocMarkerInfoWindow", owner: self.view, options: nil)!.first! as! LocMarkerInfoWindowController
            print(marker.snippet!)
            let info =  marker.snippet!.components(separatedBy: Constant.SEPARATOR_LIST_ITEM)
            infoWindow.iconMarker.image = Generic.toImageByURL(url: info[0], width: Constant.ICON_INFOWIN_MARKER_WIDTH, height: -1, defaultImage: "defaultmarker")
            infoWindow.name.text = info[1]
            infoWindow.status.text = info[2]
            infoWindow.speed.text = info[3]
            infoWindow.lastUpdatedOn.text = Double(info[4])?.getDateStringFromTimeStamp()
            infoWindow.interval.text = info[5]

            return infoWindow
        }

}
```

I will really appreciate any help regarding this. Thank you

Comment: any response on it??

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by declaring messsagingProcessor as global and using it in view controller and class.

```
let messsagingProcessor: MesssagingProcessor = MesssagingProcessor()
```

Previously, I was declaring and using different objects in view controller class and client class.

I hope it may help someone. Thanks anyway